# How to add OCSP support into Python requests library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, ocsp

Is there any way to implement OCSP checking with the *requests* library ?

The only feasible way I see now is using [pyOpenSSL](https://github.com/pyca/pyopenssl), however this means having to establish a separate independent connection to the server to get the certificate and then connect to the issuer to verify it.

And then, are there any such implementations out there ?
Did you already solve it and care to report about it ?

[M2Crypto](https://github.com/M2Crypto/M2Crypto) also looks like to be a candidate for SSL connections at least, however I'm not sure about possible drawbacks with that library, but it looks more low-level than `requests` for sure.

**Side note:**
Apparently Python really sucks when it comes to more sophisticated HTTP/HTTPS connections.

`urllib` does not even check SSL/TLS certificates while `requests` comes with its own collection of CA certificates (rather than using the system's CAs) and does not seem to support proxy configuration via PAC.

Heck, I even tried using Qt's HTTP stack (which uses OS settings) but ran into a stalling issue with multiple concurrent connections.

Comment: You can force `requests` to use your system's CAs but you have to find them first. You can pass in the `cert='/path/to/pemfile.pem'` parameter to do so. Further, our collection of CA certificates is Mozilla's certificate store with certain certificates removed. There are nightly versions built as well and it's distributed as `certifi`.

Comment: I have seen that `cert` option but as I understood it, it wants a file with PEM certificates, so how would this work with my system's CAs unless I'm running some Linux that uses a concatenation of my CAs ? Windows does not have such a file that I know of (neither does the Mac). `certifi` is just another collection that has to be updated just like `requests`, though I suppose this might be more often as `certifi`'s only purpose is providing certificates rather than functionality.

Comment: Would it be ok for the server if the request came via a `GET` the `https://ocsp-endpoint/[BASE64_DER_REQUEST]` or POST with `[BASE64_DER_REQUEST]` as the `body` key?

Answer (score 2):

From a short look at pyOpenSSL and M2Crypto I doubt that they provide the necessary functionality for OCSP verification and I cannot see any serious attempts to implement such thing for python, see also http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/bugs/1092384.

Implementing OCSP is definitely not an easy thing. The OpenSSL API is undocumented and you have to extract the necessary parts from the source code. Then you have to try to put them together and make an interface out of it, which is actually usable by an end-user.

> Apparently Python really sucks when it comes to more sophisticated HTTP/HTTPS connections.

It's not only python. If you look at tools and programming languages lots of them fail in the basic tasks of verifying certificate properly, that is check against CA and do not forget to check names inside certificate against the given host name. And most of them either don't do OCSP or provide only an OpenSSL like API which is not really usable in a simple way.

Comment: Yeah, I have not found an easy interface for OCSP either, this is why I was asking. Too bad that operating systems and various libraries do provide such functionality that can't be tapped into directly.

Answer (score 1):

Actually OpenSSL do have support for OCSP. I was actually able to have a open socket with SSL.Connection but then, my problem is to have an actual HTTP connection over that socket.

I don't know if this helps
Actually OpenSSL do have support for OCSP. I was actually able to have a open socket with SSL.Connection but then, my problem is to have an actual HTTP connection over that socket.

With the following code you can open a ocsp connection and perform the whole ocsp handshake. The next step is creating an http connection from it

```
ssl_context = Context(tls_method)
ssl_context.use_certificate_file(clientcert)
ssl_context.use_privatekey_file(clientkey)
ssl_context.load_verify_locations(cafile=None, capath=trusted_ca)
ssl_context.set_verify(VERIFY_PEER | VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT |VERIFY_CLIENT_ONCE, callback=self.verify_callback)
ssl_context.set_ocsp_client_callback(
        callback=self.ocsp_callback, data=None)
tcp_conn = socket.create_connection((host, port))
ssl_conn = Connection(ssl_context, tcp_conn)
ssl_conn.set_tlsext_host_name(host.encode())
ssl_conn.request_ocsp()
ssl_conn.set_connect_state()
ssl_conn.do_handshake()
```